# Gnuplot zrange change with pm3d

Tags: plot, gnuplot, surface

I have a data, when I plot with a line plot I get the correct minima and zrange. Depicted below [LINE plot with correct zrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDFOh.png)

```
set ticslevel 0
spl 'surf_laplace3.dat' w l
```

However, when I use pm3d the range automatically changes and so the minima. 
[pm3d plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft1I3.png)

```
set pm3d
set dgrid3d 300,300
set ticslevel 0
splot 'surf_laplace3.dat' w pm3d
```

if I use less thatn 300,300 in dgrid3d.. the density map is even low
[dat file is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vqab36w3tx5sza/surf_laplace3.dat?dl=0)
Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Can you post the gnuplot scripts used to create these two figures?

Comment: @user8153 I have added the scripts along with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `pm3d`, but is caused by `dgrid3d`. This option will cause gnuplot to interpolate the data on a 300x300 grid. Depending on the interpolation function this will change your data points.

Because your data points already form a complete grid you should not use `dgrid3d` at all. All you need to do is to make clear to gnuplot when a new row in your data starts (i.e., when the x-value changes). You can do this by adding a blank line every 301 lines in your data file. Then you get the right result simply from

```
splot "surf_laplace3.dat" w pm3d
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you tell how do I get contour lines on the surface